# Batch file to copy the file once from folder and wait for next file

Tags: file, batch-file

A software is generating text file after every few minutes in `Folder1`. The text file name starts with `RES_` and is followed by a string of digits, e.g. `RES_123456` and next time the same `RES` but new number.

I have created a batch file to copy the file from `Folder1` to `Folder2`, and just want to modify it in such a way that it should copy the file once, and if successfully copied wait for `30` seconds and then try to repeat the porocess, this time with the newly generated file.

It should not copy the same old file twice or more in 30 seconds. I can do it by increasing the timeout to `30` but then the time will start from the time I open the batch file. I want to start the time if the file is successfully copied.

```
:loop
xcopy /y "C:\Users\ahm\Desktop\Folder1\RES*.txt" "C:\Users\ahm\Desktop\Folder2"
timeout /t 5
goto loop
```

Comment: `XCopy`, _(now deprecated)_, and the utility which superseded it, `RoboCopy`, should both have some options to prevent a file being copied from the source, if it already exists in the destination. Open a Command Prompt window, and type `help robocopy`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information. Then you can repeat the same, if you must use an outdated command, but with `help xcopy`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually as soon as file get copied in destination folder another software will take the file and will keep the folder2 empty for next file. In the source folder, also the software will keep the file for 10 sec to copy.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to create an intermediate process at all! Either tell 'another software' to pick up a copy from `Folder1` instead move from `Folder2`, or tell 'software' to deposit it in `Folder2` or in both `Folder1` and `Folder2`. At the moment if you don't copy it, 'another software' has nothing to do, and if you delay for `30` seconds it's possible you'll have missed a new file, which was only deposited for `10` seconds. Honestly an essentially always running batch file is not what I'd be using for a task like this.

Comment: Such tasks are the very reason the `archive` attribute exists. both `xcopy` and `robocopy` support this attribute. (`xcopy /?`, see the `/M` switch)

Comment: I agree with @Stephan.  You will have to do a little bit of upfront work though.  Any files that already exist in the source folder you will have turn off the archive attribute first before you implement this change.  That is easily done with the `atrrib` command and only needs to be done once because after that the `XCOPY` or `Robocopy` commands will take care of toggling the attribute.